# Is it possible to combine two ranges to create a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, radio-button

Is it possible to do something join to dictionaries or two lists to make a dictionary?

```
a = dict(range(1, 97))
b = dict(range(1, 97))
c = {
     a + b
}
```

Or something like this:

```
a = range(1, 97)
b = range(1, 97)
c = {
a + b
}
```

Because I would like to create a dictionary c where the x key is 1 and the y key is 1...until x key is 96 and y key is 96.
This because I would like to crate with tkinter a frame filled with 96 selectable and indipendent elements (as SUNKEN radiobuttons).

I would like to have in my frame something like radiobutton1,1, radiobutton 2,2, radiobutton 3,3 and so on until radiobutton96,96

I will use then

```
    v = tk.IntVar()
    v.set("L")
    for ax, bx in c:
        d = ttk.Radiobutton(master, text=ax,
                        variable=v, value=bx)
        d.pack(anchor=NSWO)
```

Comment: This is not a dictionary, but a set... Please show us (in code) the expected output since it is quite unclear at the moment.

Comment: `dict.fromkeys(zip(range(...), range(...)))`? But then why not just `{(x, x): None for x in range(...)}`.

Comment: Huh? It doesn't sound like you want a `dict`, really, a iterable of pairs would do. Something like `for ax, bx in zip(range(1,96), range(1, 96)):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this:

```
a = range(1, 97)
b = range(1, 97)
```

and you want to make a dictionary, all you have to do is this:

```
c = dict(zip(a, b))
```

It works normally:

```
>>> c[1]
1
>>> c[14]
14
>>> c
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96}
```